# Electron webview spellchecker not working

Tags: electron, chromium

We are building an app which uses Electron and at one point we are popping out a window which is a third-party website. If I open the website using chrome or any other browser then the spell checking works as normal. Opening the page in a webview inside Electron it doesn't.

**Does Electron/Chromium not support spell-checking or is there something which needs to be enabled?**

Note: We have no control over the contents or code of the third-party website

Answer (score 2):

After some investigation, I found that Electron does not have a default spellchecker but there are plenty of modules which can help.

[Electron Spellchecker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-spellchecker) is the one we went for as it has good support.

Comment: @the4kman Please take more care when doing reviews. This self-answer is *clearly* **not**  a link-only answer. It answers the posted question ***"Does Electron/Chromium not support spell-checking or is there something which needs to be enabled?"*** and then supplies a workaround which is to use a module. The link was only supplying *extra* info, i.e. where to get the specific module used. (This is even clear without actually reading the question at all!!)

Comment: @robinCTS While I agree that it is, in fact, an answer to the OP’s question, it’s better to include details about setting up the module etc.

Comment: @the4kman I agree that in general it's a good idea, and for most link-answers absolutely essential, to include such details, In this case it is neither a *requirement*, nor actually directly related to the question, which concerns whether or not a built-in spellchecker exists and how to turn it on.The answer is perfectly fine even if the link were not supplied. In fact the answer stands on its own omitting the last sentence completely. This is actually the correct test to determine if an answer is close-worthy as link-only, as seen in [this meta answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/145902) by…

Comment: …a mod, especially in the last sentence. [This other answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/145901) to the same question is also very informative.

Comment: @the4kman So, to recap, if the answer stands on its own if the link is removed (or dies), then it is ***not*** a link-only answer and is not close-worthy *for that reason*. (It may still be close-worthy if, for example, it didn't actually answer the question!).

Comment: @robinCTS Thank you, this was pretty informative. I still think that the answer lacks some detail and its simply a product recommendation in its current form (which tends to be off-topic on SO), but it was interesting to see your side.

Comment: @the4kman Actually, it's interesting that you say that. Product recommendations are not off-topic per se, provided any affiliations are disclosed. They must, of course, be part of an appropriate answer. It's questions *asking* for product recommendations that are off-topic.Technically, a product recommendation answer to such a question is a valid answer, and not against the rules. It is, however, considered  bad form by some/a lot of users to answer such questions as it only encourages further asking of similarly off-topic questions.